# ERROR:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Im having a hard time debugging this SQL Query, Im getting this error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.
```

and this is my query:

```
SELECT SID,CSID,M,QCL,STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(TN) from tmpTbl FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
            from 
            (
              select t.SID, t.CSID, t.M, w.QCL,t.TC,t.TN 
              from tmpTbl AS t
              inner join WoOr AS w
              on t.WO = WoOr.WO
              where t.IsSelected = 0
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(TC)
                for TN in (STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(TN) from tmpTbl FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,''))
            ) p
```

**THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!**

Comment: Search "dynamic pivot" for some good examples.

Comment: I already searched (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324003/convert-from-access-transform-count-pivot-to-sql-server-2005/20330278?noredirect=1#comment30363083_20330278) for that but I want to be one line of code only. do you have any alternatives?

Comment: Needs to be dynamic if you aren't going to hard-code the pivot columns in.

Comment: @Unknownymous >>I want to be one line of code only<< You can't always get what you want :) Use dynamic sql or hard-coded column names.

Answer (score 1):

```
for TN in (STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(TN) from tmpTbl FOR XML   
PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,''))
```

With the pivot function, you can't do dynamic columns. They need to be hardcoded unless you resort to dynamic sql.